# XML Elements Move Inside New Descendant with Linq to XML C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this XML document:

```
<aaa>
    <x1></x1>
    <x2></x2>
    <x3></x3>
</aaa>
```

And need to convert it to this document:

```
<aaa>
    <bbb note="moved to new">
        <x1></x1>
        <x2></x2>
        <x3></x3>   
    </bbb>
</aaa>
```

Using Linq-to-XML, what would be the right code to add all child nodes of  to a new descendant , but only if  descendant does not exist? I started with this

```
var docRaw = XElement.Parse( documentString );
var bbbElem = docRaw.Elements( "aaa" ).Where( docRaw => !docRaw.Elements( "bbb" ).Any() );
```

But I think that takes me down the wrong strategy-path.

All ideas appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ReplaceNodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.replacenodes(v=vs.110).aspx) to replace the content of the root element. You can replace them with a new node named `<bbb>` that contains the root's former child elements.

```
doc.Root.ReplaceNodes(
    new XElement("bbb",
        new XAttribute("note", "moved to new"),
        doc.Root.Elements()
    )
);
```

Comment: That is great. It does seem to add an empty ns attribute, I am looking for a way to ensure that is not included.

Comment: That would seem to indicate that your actual XML is in a namespace (which your example doesn't show). If that's the case, you need to make sure that your `<bbb>` element is named appropriately.